# Bank Account Transfer Project Java

Tags: java, class, bank

I'm doing a project in Java, and I'm stuck on part of it. I have the deposit function working in SavingsAccount class, but I can't seem to figure out how to call it in the engine class. For our project, we have to allow the user to create multiple bank accounts and transfer funds between them, using the BlueJ virtual machine. I'll post the related code for my engine class and savings account class... thanks, any help would be appreciated!

Problem: I can't get the money to transfer from one account to another, I get an error message on the engine class. I think I'm doing something wrong with the account I'm sending money to...

**Savings Account Code**

```
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount
public void transfer (BankAccount that, double amount) 
 {
   if 
   (balance-amount < -80)
   balance = balance ;
   else
   {
       if 
       (amount <= balance)
            {
                this.balance = this.balance - amount;
                that.balance = that.balance + amount;
            }
       else
            {
               this.balance = this.balance - amount-20;
               that.balance = that.balance + amount;
            }
    }
 }
```

**Engine Class**

```
public class engine
{
 SavingsAccount savings1 = new SavingsAccount();
 savings1.balance = 0;

 //code for other choices, such as deposit and withdraw... 

    if (selection2 == 3)
       {
          System.out.println ("How much would you like to transfer?");
          int transferAmount = in.nextInt ( );
          System.out.println ("Which account would you like to transfer the money to?");
          String thatAccount = in.next();
          savings1.withdraw (transferAmount);
          thatAccount.deposit (transferAmount);
          System.out.println ("You account balance is " + savings1.getBalance () + "!");

      }
```

Comment: I do not undestand your question.

Comment: What ever you are doing, you should not used double there where moneys are involved. Use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: I can't get the money to transfer from one account to another, i get an error on the engine class. I think I'm doing something wrong with the account I'm sending money to...

Comment: Listen to Vash. And show the stack trace for the error.

Comment: What error? Do you expect us to write a context around these two classes and find it ourselves?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention error message. Yogendra guessed it though. I can't call the deposit method on a string, but I don't know how to change the user's string input (thatAccount) into their bank account, or to search for thatAccount's bank account...

Answer (score 3):

I have some obervation/suggestions as below:

Your transferAccount `thatAccount` is a String `String thatAccount = in.next();`. How can you call `deposit ()` method on that?

I don't see `deposit()` and `withdraw()` methods in `SavingsAccount` class, hope there are present in `BankAccount` class.

Now sure how you are initializing the balance as `saving1.balance=0;`. It should be done through some class method e.g. `setBalance` as `saving1.setBalance(0);`.

When you are invoking `savings1.withdraw()` method, the balance is `0`.

Hope these will help you in identifying your issue and correcting the program.

Comment: thats what I need help with. How do I 'find' the user's selected transfer destination. I realize that right now it is just a string, but I really don't know what to do from that point. I have very limited experience in java...

Comment: Not sure, how much I can help here but you need to follow some basic steps in your engine class. 1. Define a map as `Map<String, SavingsAccount> maintainedAccounts = new HashMap<String, SavingsAccount>();`. 2. Instantiate the accounts and put in the map as `maintainedAccounts.put("acountNumber123",savings1);`. 3. To before `withdraw` or `depost`, get the bank account as `SavingsAccount accountToMaintain = maintainedAccounts.get("accountNumber123");`. 4. Call the desired function on the retrieved bank object e.g. `accountToMaintain.deposit(1000);` or `accountToMaintain.withdraw(500);`.